# Erro de cors com laravel 5.1

Tags: ajax, laravel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Pessoal estou tendo problemas com o CORS em minha aplicação laravel 5.1, quando faço uma requisição via RESTLET ele retorna sem problemas. No entanto se uma mesma requisição for feita via AJAX ele gera o ERRO de cors. O que faço? já me deparei com isso antes e consegui arrumar, porem nesse caso não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Essa sua requisição AJAX está saindo de qual domínio?

Comment: são dois dominios diferentes, ambos estão local.

Comment: Tenta adicionar o domínio ao CORS no laravel https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1 está em inglês espero ajudar.

Comment: puts ja fiz isso, não funcionou. muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Adiciona o código na sua dúvida para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Eu subi a aplicação para um dominio. e coloquei a imagem.

Comment: Você adicionou assim ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’)?

Comment: sim. no Cors.php                                                                                    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
        return $next($request);
    }

Answer (score -1):

Fabricio,

adiciona a class CORS app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php

```
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
    }
}
```

e tenta registrar ele no Kernel app/Http/kernel.php

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
```

foi assim que implementou o seu CORS?

Comment: cara esta exatamente assim. Mas não funciona.

Comment: Chegou a fazer um `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: cheguei, o engraçado e que via RESTLET ou POSTMAIN ele retorna

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');

Route::group(['/' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'controller_api@request');
});                     Inseri ate nas rotas, alem de esta puxando o middleware

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda SylvioT

Comment: Marque como resposta se ajudei, disponha!

Answer (score -1):

SOLUÇÃO 
Foi feita a inserção da rota desta forma abaixo .
`Route::post('/', 'controller_api@request')->name('/')->middleware('cors');`

**Detalhe IMPORTANTE: assim que for feito a inclusão do 
 `'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,` em Kernal.php , não adicione mais nada relacionado ao Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Por exemplo :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```